# Primefaces 3.5 multisort failure on pagination .. do we have fix?

Tags: primefaces

Primefaces 3.5 introduced multisort on dataTable. But it has a bug with pagination.

Everytime paginator button is pressed, the sort column(sortMeta obj of the col) set at the time of table initial render is sent to the load method and not the selected sort column(s). If the initial sortOrder is not set, a null is sent.

Has there been a fix to this problem? Does anybody know if this has been fixed in any of the Elite versions? Or if there is a workaround for it?

Need some urgent help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to overcome the problem by doing some additional coding in the application. This wouldn't be needed if the original bug is fixed in the later versions.

My solution

I have added 2 ajax events, for 'sort' and 'page' on the table. I saw that on each 'sort' the table had the right list of multisortmeta, but on the pagination call, it was getting over written with initial data.

So I have saved the list of multisortmeta in the bean on each sort call and on pagination call i have over written the table's list of multisortmeta with what i have in the bean. My bean is a session bean hence there is no problem with saving the list.

Once this is done the multisort is working on pagination. Below is my code

view/xhtml code

```
                <p:dataTable id="userDataTable"
                value="#{userBean.userModel}" var="usr"
                paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" sortMode="multiple"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="20,40,60" rows="20"
                sortBy="#{userBean.preSortOrder}" lazy="true"
                resizableColumns="false" >

            <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{userBean.onPage}" ></p:ajax> 
            <p:ajax event="sort" listener="#{userBean.onSort}" ></p:ajax>
```

Bean code

```
public void onSort( SortEvent event) {
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    UIComponent tableComp = viewRoot.findComponent("userForm:userDataTable");
    DataTable table = ((DataTable)tableComp);
    preSortOrder = table.getMultiSortMeta();
 }
    public void onPage() {
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    UIComponent tableComp = viewRoot.findComponent("userForm:userDataTable");
    DataTable table = ((DataTable)tableComp);
    table.setMultiSortMeta(preSortOrder);       
}
```

Hope this will be useful to others as well.